# natbib: citing edition (by others) of collected works of a single author

Tags: natbib

I need to include the following reference in a paper:

> Saussure, Ferdinand de. 2014. *Writings in General Linguistics*, ed. Simon Bouquet, Rudolf Engler, Carol Sanders, and Matthew Pires. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

The entry in my bib file looks as follows.

```
@book{saussure14,
Author = {Saussure, Ferdinand de},
Title = {{Writings in General Linguistics}},
Editor = {Bouquet, Simon and Engler, Rudolf and Sanders, Carol and Pires, Matthew},
Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
Address = {Oxford},
Year = {2014}}
```

I'm using `natbib.sty` and `linquiry2.bst`. When I compile the pdf, I get the following.

[image]

Short of hacking `linquiry2.bst`, is there a generalized way of getting this kind of bibliographic entry?

---

EDIT (16/03): MWE, as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

Theoretical syntax rocks, as noted in \citet{saussure14}.

\bibliographystyle{linquiry2}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Where `refs.bib` includes solely the book entry above. Screenshot of compiled pdf.

[image]

Comment: I want the reference to display the names of the volume editors (see the bib entry at the top of my original post), so that it reads

Saussure, Ferdinand de. 2014. Writings in General Linguistics. Simon Bouquet, Rudolf Engler, Carol Sanders, Matthew Pires (eds.). Oxford: Oxford University Press. 

Which is the proper reference, as per the OUP site for the book (https://global.oup.com/academic/product/writings-in-general-linguistics-9780199261444).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have that one entry with editors, you can change the Title field in `refs.bib` to the following:

```
Title = {{Writings in General Linguistics}\emph{, ed. Simon Bouquet, Rudolf Engler, Carol Sanders, and Matthew Pires}},
```

That should produce exactly the result you're looking for. No need to change anything else.

If that's ugly, other options are using `custom-bib`, hacking `linquiry2.bst` (as you mentioned), or switching to BibLaTex.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a bit of reading and I assume you chose the bibliography style because of some external requirement. The `linquiry2` has been designed to adhere completely to the specifications set out by the editors of *Linguistic Inquiry*.

In their submission guidelines, it is clearly stated that books should be cited using *either* the author(s) or the editor(s). As such, the only correct solution to your problem is to delete the `Author` tag in your .bib file. Using your MWE and the edited bibliography entry

```
@book{saussure14,
Title = {{Writings in General Linguistics}},
Editor = {Bouquet, Simon and Engler, Rudolf and Sanders, Carol and Pires, Matthew},
Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
Address = {Oxford},
Year = {2014}}
```

The resulting document looks like this:
[image]

If you want both author and editor in your bibliography, the simplest solution is to find or create a style which supports this. Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

Try @incollection with booktitle instead of title:

```
@incollection{saussure14,
Author = {Saussure, Ferdinand de},
Editor = {Bouquet, Simon and Engler, Rudolf and Sanders, Carol and  Pires, Matthew},
booktitle = {{Writings in General Linguistics}},
Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
Address = {Oxford},
Year = {2014}}
```

This works fine for me (except there's an "In" which maybe bothers you):

[image]

If you want to hack linquiry2.sty, just [click](http://en.file-upload.net/download-11414173/linquiry2.bst.html) or find FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle} and replace it with:

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
{ "" }
{ editor empty$
    %% Added: "t" change.case$  (Alexis)
    { word.in booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize * }
    { booktitle "t" change.case$ emphasize
      ", " *
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { bbl.editors }
        { bbl.editor }
      if$
      * " " *
      format.in.editors *
    }
  if$
 }
if$
}
```

You will get this:

[image]